# how can can I make eyelashes follow eyelids when I close them?

Tags: vertices, shape-keys

[image]I'm trying to make it so eyelashes follow along eyelids but everything I've tried either didn't do anything or turn out right. I thought shape keys would help but couldn't find anything online about it so I can only make the eyelids themselves blink so far.

Any solution would be appreciated as I been stuck on this for days.

Here's the file uploaded
https://workupload.com/file/rRKCX5fsPs8

Comment: Hellp, hard to help withoit the file or at least a screenshot

Comment: Yeah my bad. I'm still trying to figure out how to even share a blend. File (keeps popping up no new files to pack so don't know what to do about that) and was struggling to find out where my screenshots were going.

Comment: Use a platform like workupload and share the link

Comment: Here's the uploaded file: https://workupload.com/file/rRKCX5fsPs8

Comment: So maybe the simplest way to do it is to join the eyelashe objects to the head object and to shapekey them with the eyelids?

Comment: How would I go about shape keying them to the eyelids after I joined them?

Comment: You need to select the second shapekey, switch to edit mode and move the eyelashes as well, the problem being that the interpolation may not work well. The other solution is to create some bones

Comment: Makes sense. Very much appreciated! It worked but I see what needs improvements. Bones might even be a better option than shape keying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a **driver** for 2 shape keys, you define a function like **var1=var 2**, **var1** is the eyelid, **var2** is the eyelash.
You can copy the **driver** and paste it into the expression.
I learned about it from this great tutorial: [Drivers playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbjn7kaP877u1sX4zl081V8jUeSHDY18G&si=a1gPifD02Ib_pFqE)

Comment: SWEET! I just now started looking into drivers too. Never knew that's what they could be used for. Thanks!